# How add push notification service on ghost blog?

Tags: push-notification, ghost

Most of the push notification services required to upload two files at the "/" (root) of the server . So that the following files can be accessed via the following urls
1. https://example.com/menifest.json
2. https://example.com/worker.js

Can any one help me regarding how to serve this files at the above urls in a ghost powered blog?

Comment: interesting. do you mean browserwise push?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Zapier integration for the push notifications
https://zapier.com/apps/ghost/integrations/onesignal

This guide will help you on integrating the integration above.
https://ghost.org/integrations/zapier/

Ghost blog also supports webhooks in case you would like to create a push notification service from scratch without any integration.
https://ghost.org/docs/webhooks/

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the files in your theme root and that will simply work.

1. Sign in to your admin dashboard.
2. Go to Settings -> Design and download your active theme.
3. Extract the theme files and copy the files that has to served from the root of your blog to the root folder of your theme.
4. Zip the theme.
5. Click **Upload a theme** button in your Ghost admin dashboard and upload the theme again. Don't forget to activate the theme.